# Notifying live wallpaper service about changes in settings

Tags: android

I'm creating a live wallpaper by extending WallpaperService and Engine classes. The wallpaper doesn't change frequently, so to avoid unnecessary CPU usage, I only draw the wallpaper on certain events (touch, visibilityChanged, etc.). I'm also using PreferenceFragment to generate a settings activity for the wallpaper.

Problem: when user changes a preference in the settings activity, I like the wallpaper to get notified and redraw itself ASAP using the new settings. But since I only read the settings and draw the wallpaper on certain events, the change in wallpaper doesn't happen until those events are fired.

Would appreciate solutions :) thnx.

Anybody? :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got two options. Either check the preference values in `onVisibilityChanged()` and update the wallpaper accordingly. Or use an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` to let your `Engine` know when the user has changed the preference.

**Example of the latter.**

Let your `Engine` implement the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` interface.

```
private class MyEngine extends Engine implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    // A reference to our shared prefs;
    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) { 
        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);

        mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        // Register an OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener to our shared prefs
        mPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);         

        // Your existing code ...            
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Don't forget to unregister the listener
        mPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);  
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

        // Whenever the user changes a setting, this method will be called.
        // So do what needs to be done here, like redrawing the wallpaper
        redrawWallpaper();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I can make my app more efficient. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to draw your wallpaper every frame, but Pause and Resume the rendering on the Wallpaper when the visility changed ( WallpaperService.Engine.onVisibilityChanged(boolean) ) 
You can do it by calling your GLSurfaceView.onResume() and onPause().

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/wallpaper/WallpaperService.Engine.html#onVisibilityChanged(boolean) 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html

Comment: I already have the pause and resume implemented, but I just didn't want to read the whole preferences on every onVisibilityChanged call. But thanks for the answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking out for the same thing and i discovered a solution of my own; u can use Live Data in your settings activity and then observe it in your service. This makes it a lot easier.